# When would you use '@' expression to mute PHP error messages, rather than just debugging the issue?

Tags: php, error-handling

Curious as to situations you would mask error messages in PHP using the "@" expression instead of fixing the error.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer, but this seems primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Virtually never. You could probably get away with `if(@$_POST['foo']) {}` to avoid having to do an `isset()` check.

Comment: @ceejayoz could you see a project using @ and still be considered stable? More so, I guess my question is if '@' is accepted as standard practice in final projects? I've always thought @ is only temporary way to mute messages but should never be left when publishing your completed work.

Comment: To expand on the answer from @ceejayoz -- there is virtually never a legit reason to use `@`, *even in development*. Don't mute messages. Standard practice is to write code that doesn't generate them.

Comment: TIL thanks @AlexHowansky

Comment: Also note the new `??` operator is wonderful for shortcuts to avoid lots of `isset()` calls.

Comment: Could you link me Alex? I don't see any documentation yet, what version of php?

Comment: @nopnotme https://lornajane.net/posts/2015/new-in-php-7-null-coalesce-operator